Large Data Set in ng-multiselect-dropdown
I am using ng-multiselect-dropdown in my angular project. There is a table in which each entry will have ng-multiselect-dropdown. And each dropdown will have 2k entries approx and table itself can have thousands of entry. So ui rendering is very slow because of large dataset of dropdowns.
Question 1: What I want is to load dropdown data only when user opens any dropdown otherwise it should be empty ,is there any way to do that?
          <ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'select Food'" [settings]="dropdownSettings" [data]="foodList"
            [(ngModel)]="element.foodList"
            (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event, true)" (onDeSelect)="onItemSelect($event, false)" 
            [disabled]="accessMap[element.food]">
          </ng-multiselect-dropdown>


https://github.com/NileshPatel17/ng-multiselect-dropdown/issues/149
